# Calculate areas of new features in merged layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have merged four different layers into one new one in QGIS, but I want this layer to have different information then the old layers. I want all the buffered 'islands' to have a different ID and a calculated area. However, now in the attribute table I just see four features, one for each layer that I merged. Is there a way to update the attribute table to consist of new features (one for each 'island')?

This is what the layer looks like:
[image]

And this is what the attribute table now looks like:
[image]

And this is what I want (the 5th and 6th column especially):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must create a feature for each monopart geometry, you can achieve this using the [25.1.18.46. Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=multipart%20single%20part#multipart-to-singleparts) tool, and then use the field calculator to get the area, you can find here how to calculate area [Calculating polygon areas in shapefile using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/calculating-polygon-areas-in-shapefile-using-qgis).